# Descriptive text around a matrix

Tags: matrices

I am trying to write a matrix with a bit of text sidewards and above it in order to explain its meaning.
At the moment, this is my code:

```
\begin{equation}
 \begin{turn}{90}
 \mbox{\# rows}
 \end{turn}
\stackrel{\mbox{\# columns}}{
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{pmatrix}
 }
\end{equation}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

However, the text on the left side of the matrix is not correctly centered (it is too high).
How to center the text around the matrix correctly?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48597/14757

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's easier with an `array` and `\rotatebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{@{}c@{\hspace{1ex}}c@{}}
 & \text{\# columns} \\[1ex]
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\text{\# rows}} &
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why to use `@{}`? The `c` alignment is not enough to centre the array contents?

Comment: @Sigur The additional space on the sides may be unwanted depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

Just because I like doing things with stacks...

The inter-column gap can be adjusted by changing the `2ex` argument to `\setstacktabbedgap`.  Vertical row separation is adjusted with the argument to `\setstackgap{L}{`length`}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, graphicx, tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\setstacktabbedgap{2ex}
\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\text{\# rows}}
\stackon{%
\parenMatrixstack{
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
}
}{\text{\# columns}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you can do with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row,first-col]
& \Block{1-5}{\mbox{\# columns}}\\
\Block{5-1}<\rotate>{\mbox{\# rows}}
&  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
&  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
&  1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
&  1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
 \end{pNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]